# What happens when a comma is not placed following an existing field name in SQL

Tags: sql, select

This is with regard to the [SQL Tryit Editor](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all) provided by W3 Schools. (Saying this just in case it is an environment-specific problem)

The code `SELECT CustomerName, Address, City, PostalCode FROM Customers;` yields the following output,

[image]

While code `SELECT CustomerName, Address City, PostalCode FROM Customers;` is executed, I get the following result

[image]

Clearly, the missing comma has resulted in not displaying the Address field. But this is distinct from the error message that otherwise comes when a field name is either not correct or not correctly separated. It seems to recognize `Address` to be an existing field, while it considers to display only the field immediately before the comma.

What is the logic behind the correct use of commas? Does that mean any number of correctly named fields, but without a follow up comma, will be ignored?

Comment: The second version won't even run on most databases.  Are you using MySQL or SQLite?  Don't even rely on the syntax in the second version.

Comment: The missing comma is causing it to be read as a column alias (as in `ADDRESS as CITY`, and you can see that by looking at the data in that column ("120 Hanover Sq" is clearly an address, not a city name).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Commas are used to separate the fields, when you miss a comma like you have, the 2nd column will be considered as the column alias. Here Address City means, pick the column Address and name it City. You can see in your 2nd screenshot, values from Address column are picked but the name of the column is City.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question.

Comment: How is not answering the question?

Comment: What in return happens to the original `City` field?

Comment: As per the SQL, you did not pick the City field (you just used an alias), if you want to pick it, add a comma. Also multiple fields without comma (like Address City PostalCode) should give an error.

Answer (score 2):

@Pale is right.

Your query

```
SELECT CustomerName, Address City, PostalCode FROM Customers;
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT CustomerName, Address AS City, PostalCode FROM Customers;
```

We can clearly see on your second screenshot that the data from Address is in the column called City.

However, this would most likely not work (notice the third missing comma)

```
SELECT CustomerName, Address City PostalCode FROM Customers;
```

That being said, I'm not sure if the missing *AS* would work in all DB engines.

More info on aliases can be found here.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Answer (score 1):

Some SQL dialects (notably MySQL) interpret this as an alias: They read

```
SELECT CustomerName, Address City, PostalCode FROM Customers;
```

as if it were

```
SELECT CustomerName, Address AS City, PostalCode FROM Customers;
```

which of course means: Select the `Address` column, but rename it to `City`

There are good uses for aliases, notably when you want operations (mostly joins) to run on the same column but with a different context.

Comment: Oracle, Postgres, SQL Server too

Comment: ... and SQLite and ... I think it's even standard SQL. The `AS` is optional.

Comment: and Firebird and DB2. If there is any engine that requires AS it is not one of the ones available at https://dbfiddle.uk/